# Get Users end point location using Uber API

Tags: android, uber-api

I've been looking at the UBER API and i was wondering if there was a way to have a service running in my Android / iOS app, where my app could get the users drop-off location.

The way i'm thinking about it now is the following scenario:
- The user is in a UBER car going to destination
- My app gets notified of the drop off location(lat,long) location
- My app suggests things that they can do around their drop off location, via a notification.

Is such a use case possible ?

I am interested in [this API](https://developer.uber.com/docs/v1-requests-current)

Particularly in this information:
"destination":{
      "latitude":37.7766874,
      "longitude":-122.394857,
      "eta":19
   }

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a use case is possible and explained in more details in the following links:

- [Uber Trip Experiences documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/tutorial-trip-experiences)
- [Uber Developers Blog - Uber Trip Experiences](https://devblog.uber.com/uber-trip-experiences-api-update/)
- [Uber News Room - Introducing Uber Trip Experiences](https://newsroom.uber.com/trip-experiences-api/)

To build this trip experience you have to request the [all_trips OAuth scope](https://developer.uber.com/docs/scopes) from the user:

> all_trips
>
> Get details of the trip that the user is currently taking, regardless
>   of how it was requested (via the Uber app or a third-party
>   application).
>
> Privileged

It is a privileged scope because it is required that you request access first from Uber for the scope to be usable in the application you defined in the [Uber Developer Dashboard](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard)

Then after you make an Uber ride request on behalf of the user using the [POST /v1/requests](https://developer.uber.com/docs/v1-requests), you can call either the [GET /v1/requests/current](https://developer.uber.com/docs/v1-requests-current) or [GET /v1/requests/{request_id}](https://developer.uber.com/docs/v1-requests-details) to get the details of the trip:

```
{
   "request_id":"17cb78a7-b672-4d34-a288-a6c6e44d5315",
   "status":"accepted",
   "location":{
      "latitude":37.7886532015,
      "longitude":-122.3961987534,
      "bearing":135
   },
   "pickup":{
      "latitude":37.7872486012,
      "longitude":-122.4026315287,
      "eta":5
   },
   "destination":{
      "latitude":37.7766874,
      "longitude":-122.394857,
      "eta":19
   },
   "driver": {
      "phone_number": "(555)555-5555",
      "rating": 5,
      "picture_url": "https:\/\/d1w2poirtb3as9.cloudfront.net\/img.jpeg",
      "name": "Bob"
   },
   "vehicle":{
      "make": "Bugatti",
      "model": "Veyron",
      "license_plate": "I<3Uber",
      "picture_url": "https:\/\/d1w2poirtb3as9.cloudfront.net\/car.jpeg"
   },
   "surge_multiplier":1.0,
   "eta": 5
}
```

- If your app doesn't make ride requests, you have to poll the [GET /v1/requests/current](https://developer.uber.com/docs/v1-requests-current) endpoint. See [this](https://developer.uber.com/docs/tutorial-trip-experiences#section-best-practices) and [this](https://developer.uber.com/docs/tutorials-rides-api#section-processing-a-request) for best practices.
- If your app makes ride requests, the above /v1/requests endpoints can be combined with the [Webhooks](https://developer.uber.com/docs/webhooks) event driven mechanism, so that you are notified on your server that a trip's [status has been updated](https://developer.uber.com/docs/tutorials-rides-api#section-life-cycle-of-a-request) or the receipt is ready, instead of you having to poll every 3-5 seconds to get the most up-to-date details possible.

When you receive a notification from Uber via webhooks you then call the [GET /v1/requests/current](https://developer.uber.com/docs/v1-requests-current) or [GET /v1/requests/{request_id}](https://developer.uber.com/docs/v1-requests-details) endpoint.

Then with the data you received you need to inform your Android service (by a server to client communication mechanism, e.g. websocket, push notifications, etc.) that new information is available from Uber and based on that you show to the user relevant information given the 'Trip Context' data you want to use, e.g.:
- Current location (latitude/longitude)
- Pickup location (latitude/longitude)
- ETA to pickup (while the car is arriving)
- Destination location (latitude/longitude)
- ETA to destination (while the user is in the car)

The webhook receives the following events:

- [REQUESTS.STATUS_CHANGED](https://developer.uber.com/docs/webhooks#section--requests-status_changed-)

  > For all Requests made by your application on
  >   behalf of Uber riders, we will make a request to your WEBHOOK URL
  >   whenever its status changes. This can help you notify the user or
  >   change the state of your app to reflect a status change without
  >   continuously polling the /v1/requests endpoint.
- [REQUESTS.RECEIPT_READY](https://developer.uber.com/docs/webhooks#section--requests-receipt_ready-)

  > For all Requests made by your application on behalf of Uber riders we
  >   will make a request to your WEBHOOK URL whenever a Request Receipt is
  >   available. This will allow you to show your user the details of their
  >   fare and how much they were charged as soon as their Receipt is
  >   available. If the rider cancels after the grace period, and they are
  >   charged, a receipt will still be available showing that charge.
  >
  > To get access to a Request Receipt resource, the user must have
  >   authorized your application to have access to the request_receipt
  >   scope.

[image: Uber request states]

Comment: Thanks so much for replying

I understand the oAuth section and the webhooks(which is awesome, cause then my app doesn't have to keep on checking on the status and then i have to deal with battery draining issues :)).

The one thing i'm not clear on is - Do i have to do a  POST /v1/requests ? Becuase i don't want my app to initiate the ride, but rather i want my app to be aware that there is a ride in progress and then through the webhooks you can get a status changed as you described.

Comment: If you don't want to make ride requests, you can call [GET /v1/requests/current](https://developer.uber.com/docs/v1-requests-current) with an access token which has the [all_trips scope](https://developer.uber.com/docs/scopes) and trip details will be returned for the current request/trip irrespective of which application initiated it. all_trips is a privileged scope and you need to request access to it from Uber in the Developers Dashboard for your app. "Access trip details about all future Uber trips. Including pickup, destination, and real-time location for all of your future rides"

Comment: But, there is a downside You will not be notified in the web hook URL with status updates if the ride request is not made by your application. As the [web hooks docs](https://developer.uber.com/docs/webhooks#section-events) says this: "For all Requests made by your application on behalf of Uber riders, we will make a request to your WEBHOOK URL whenever its status changes". You have to poll, see [this](https://developer.uber.com/docs/tutorial-trip-experiences#section-best-practices) and [this](https://developer.uber.com/docs/tutorials-rides-api#section-processing-a-request) for best practices

Comment: Sorry one last comment here. I wish the Uber app would broadcast an intent, and apps with the right credentials would be able to consume that and act accordingly :(. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: I agree, a better design is definitely possible. In the meantime, I think polling on your own server on behalf of the user and sending a downstream push notification to your device when the status changes is a good option in terms of battery life and overall performance. For a good push notification server side library for Android and iOS (if you use Google Cloud Messaging for iOS) I recommend [python-gcm](https://github.com/geeknam/python-gcm)

Comment: @user1352234 According to the [Changelog](https://developer.uber.com/docs/change-log) as of 2016-03-10 Uber added support for receiving status changes in your webhook for all trips by using the all_trips.status_changed webhooks event type. See the updated [Trip Experiences](https://developer.uber.com/docs/tutorial-trip-experiences) and [WebHooks page](https://developer.uber.com/docs/webhooks#section--all_trips-status_changed-)

Comment: Thanks for this. Does this now mean that even if my app didn't request the ride. I can make use of webhooks, after i have received permission from the user with the all_trips privilage, i can receive updates from the the UBER servers to my webhook and down to my client app via a push notification ? Would that scenario now be possible ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what's possible.

Comment: Awesome thanks Mnemonic. You have been very helpful.